# Samsung rfg238aars Fridge working - Freezer Not

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

My Samsung rfg238aars refrigerator has been giving me a lot of issues. The fridge compartment is working, but the freezer will not cool at all.

Here’s the sequence of issues in order as they happened:

1. The freezer was leaking. Cleaned the evap line, did not fix problem.
2. Freezer was icing over, really bad.
3. Heard a loud grinding/humming noise. Evaporator fan seems to be running when I checked.
4. Humming/grinding noise stopped. Freezer stopped working altogether. Cleaned condenser coils. No luck.

I’ve been searching for answers online but can’t pinpoint what the issue is.

Comment: What does the freezer digital display indicate? Is it giving you an error reading? How old is the fridge?

Comment: There’s no error display other than when I unplug it, 6A/88 and 88. I believe 2014? We bought it used.

Comment: I was going to suggest you unplug it and then plug it in again. Sounds like you did that. Sometimes that will reset the logic board.